# Mongoose populate returns null

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have been searching for this for hours now. But none of the solutions worked or me.

I have two models.

Articles:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const articlesSchema = new Schema({
    articleHeader: String,
    articleBody: String,
    byUserId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user'},
    additionDate: Date,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('articles', articlesSchema, 'ArticlesInfo');
```

Users:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    fname: String,
    lname: String,
    email: String,
    pwd: String,
    dob: Date,
    gender: String,     
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema, 'UserInfo');
```

And my query goes like this:

```
router.get('/articles', function(req,res){

    article.find().populate("byUserId").sort({"additionDate": -1}).exec(function(err, articl) {
        if(err) {
            res.send("Error! " + err);
        } else {
            console.log(articl);
            res.json(articl);
        }
    });

});
```

But my output is always:

```
    {
        "_id": "5a13254a081af40d6c55654e",
        "additionDate": "2017-11-20T18:56:10.951Z",
        "byUserId": null,
        "articleBody": "Body 1",
        "articleHeader": "Header 1",
        "__v": 0,
    }
```

When I remove the populate,"byUserId" is returning ObjectId.

Comment: Can you tell me why you are using that .sort({"additionDate": -1}) ?

Comment: To sort the output as per "additionDate" values in descending order,

Comment: Are this two models in same file or different file?

Comment: Both are in different files.

Comment: Ohk. Your code looks correct but you can give a  try what I wrote in answer.